# Improve model accuracy in multi-classification problem

Tags: neural-network, classification, multiclass-classification, accuracy, mlp

I use a MLP to classify three different classes A, B, C. The `loss function` I use is `categorical cross entropy` and the optimiser is `adam`. To estimate my models performance I use 10-fold Cross Validation. On average i get `60% accuracy score` but I need it to be higher. The confusion matrix for the classes A,B,C, I get is the following:

| Class A | Class B | Class C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 14440 | 8118 | 11229 |
| 6045 | 21863 | 5879 |
| 6207 | 4264 | 23315 |

The amount of data points I have for each class is sufficiently large and equal (the ratio is 1:1:1). I was trying to see how the model would fare, if instead of 3 classes it classified two classes. Each time I remove from the dataset the data points of the class I wont be using. So when I train it to classify data points between class B and C I get around `80% accuracy score`and the following confusion matrix:

| Class B | Class C |
| --- | --- |
| 26456 | 7331 |
| 6255 | 27531 |

However when I train the model to classify data points between A and C i get around `69.5%` and the following confusion matrix:

| Class A | Class C |
| --- | --- |
| 22180 | 11607 |
| 9659 | 24127 |

For the classes A and B I get around `72% accuracy score` and the following confusion matrix:

| Class A | Class B |
| --- | --- |
| 23971 | 9816 |
| 9616 | 24170 |

In all cases the `precision score`, `recall score` and `f1 score` are more or less equal to the accuracy score.

- Could the reason why I get low accuracy when I classify the 3 classes be class A?
- Maybe some data points from class A are too similar with data points from class B and others are too similar with data points of class C?

  If so what could I do to improve the score provided that I can't improve the dataset.

Comment: It's true that class A seems to be slightly harder to identify than B or C, but it's not that big a difference. It's clear that the problem becomes a bit harder with 3 classes, since you obtain 60% instead of at least 69% in all the binary cases (this is expected). Did you check that there is no overfitting? You can also try other models, but if the features are not sufficiently good indicators there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: @Erwan Doesnt 10-fold cross validation reduce overfitting? (at least to some extent) I will see how other models perform too. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: No, CV doesn't reduce overfitting, it's only useful to obtain a reliable estimate of the performance. You should check overfitting by measuring performance on the training set: if it's much higher than on the test set, then there is overfitting.